# X-Plane / F-4 question -- policy on sim related questions

Tags: discussion, scope, off-topic, on-topic

[image]

The [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/52390/14897) went through [multiple](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/52390/timeline) close and low-quality reviews.

Timeline of events:

- Asker can't find flaps lever
- Answer shows flap switch on the real plane (photo and manual)
- Another answer shows (?) a barely visible flap *indicator* in a 10-year old (?) add-on for FSX
- Asker clarifies they still can't find it in X-Plane
- I respond to the asker's comment on the answer that asking about the real plane is on-topic, asking where it is in X-Plane after being shown the real life one is off-topic
- A user edits the question invalidating the top voted answer
- I roll it back based on [community policy](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3103/14897).

A lot of the comments are both for and against the question.

- What are your thoughts so the community can establish a policy with regard to those questions? What should be done to the question?

Comment: I agree this is a dupe and the main issues are covered in that previous question. I think both it and you are right: asking for real-life information to be used in a sim is fine, but asking why a specific sim differs from real life isn't. The only answer we can give in that case is "ask the software provider", which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 3):

My opinion is as I have commented twice:

- Asking a question stemming from a sim is on-topic if it is about the real life application of that question. Pursuing product support is off-topic.

Similar situations where I have previously answered:

- [Is center tank fuel required to start the 737-800 engines?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47777/14897)
- [How to guess the actual name of the SID, waypoint, etc., if you have never seen it when told by ATC?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47824/14897)

Those are questions coming from aviation enthusiasts, and for example the 737 one in OP's own words:

> Is it like that in real life?

What I think should be done to the question is for it to be re-opened, whether OP accepts an answer or not.

I also think all answers for such questions should not be product support answers (products have their own forums and support teams and online groups).

---

**Update:**

The above aligns with the older topic/policy on the same scope problem:

- [The scope of Flight Simulation questions on the Aviation SE](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/307/14897)

> In summary, I'm all for questions that ask about airplane procedures and if the simmers want to frame the questions in this regard, that is fine. I just don't want to see "so what button do I press in X-plane to do something" questions.

I'll leave this question open, i.e., leave VTC as duplicate to the community -- so anyone wanting to answer can do so in case the community thinks a policy refresh is needed.